# Kubernetes: Service routing to pods with multiple containers

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I am currently facing an issue in my Kubernetes cluster. While debugging that I had a question in mind which I didn't know the answer to.

I am using AWS EKS, version 1.15 but I don't think my question is related to any specific cloud or kubernetes version

I have a deployment. It has multiple containers. There is a service that exposes this deployment.

Suppose the deployment has 2 containers, C1 and C2. C1 takes 1 second to start but C2 takes 30 seconds to start(crazy!). So, when I start the pod at time t1, what happens is that once C1 starts immediately and the pod goes into running status but only 1/2 containers are ready. The pod C2 finally starts at time t2(t1+30seconds). At time t2, 2/2 containers are ready.

Also assume that C1 takes the incoming request from the service, it does something and then forwards request to C2, C2 does something and then returns it to C1. C1 finally returns to service and the response is served to client.

So, my question is, during the time between t2 and t1, when pod is in running state but only 1/2 container is ready, would the service forward requests to the pods?

Put another way, when does the service forward request to pods? If they are in running state and not matter how many containers are ready? OR if they are in running state and all containers are ready?

My thinking is that service won't forward as it won't make any sense if all the pods are not ready but I don't have any proof/document to justify it.

Comment: Okay, so I got my answer. If all the containers of a pod are not ready, the traffic does not go to the pod. The endpoint of a pod is only added to a service if all the containers are ready. I described my service when the 1/2 containers were ready. The pod IP did not appear in the service endpoints. When 2/2 containers got ready, only then it added pod IP to service endpoints. Thanks to all who answered. It was silly on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...when pod is in running state but only 1/2 container is ready, would the service forward requests to the pods?

No.

> when does the service forward request to pods?
> If they are in running state and not matter how many containers are ready? OR if they are in running state and all containers are ready?

> My thinking is that service won't forward as it won't make any sense if all the pods are not ready but I don't have any proof/document to justify it.

[Here it is](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) :)

Official documentation says that "...the kubelet uses readiness probes to know when a container is ready to start accepting traffic. **A Pod is considered ready when all of its containers are ready**. One use of this signal is to control which Pods are used as backends for Services. When a Pod is not ready, it is removed from Service load balancers..."

Additionally it says:

"...applications are temporarily unable to serve traffic... an application might depend on external services ... In such cases, you don't want to kill the application, but you don’t want to send it requests either. Kubernetes provides readiness probes to detect and mitigate these situations. A pod with containers reporting that they are not ready does not receive traffic through Kubernetes Services..."

Readiness probe is used to detect the situation when traffic shall not be sent to App.

> My thinking is that service won't forward as it won't make any sense if all the pods are not ready

You are absolutely right here.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make your scenario more understandable, lets call them **web** and **api**. those are the components of our service and while **web** will be ready in seconds, the **api** component will need more time.

First things first, we need to decide our deployment strategy. If we put **web** and **api** in the same deployment, then the **service** object on top of this deployment will enforce the definitions on both of them. So if you want to expose your **web** service on port 443, then the **api** will also be exposed on port 443. Yes, you can label those and set different definitions, but this is far from ideal.

We can say that the **service** objects in Kubernetes world acts like a **load-balancer**. So if you put two different components on the same deployment, and define a service object on top of them, then when you call your service from an outside network, you will end up reaching **web** or **api** endpoints, randomly.

You can check this image out for visualization: [Kubernetes Service Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ1Al.png)

In an ideal world, you need to deploy this application in two different deployments, because they can be de-coupled and serves for different purposes. After deploying those, all you need to do is to deploy two different services to expose your deployments. From my understanding, the **api** is only operating in the internal network, so it can be **[headless-service](https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8#:%7E:text=A%20headless%20service%20is%20a,spec.)**.

First things first, let's create a namespace (or project) for the application.

```
kubectl create ns myapp
```

And define our deployment So for our **web** component, let's define the deployment file;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9376
```

and the service which exposes our web deployment to the outside network

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: web
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

You can see that the **web-deployment** deployment object has three replicas and the **web-service** service definition will load-balance the incoming requests accordingly.

Now, let's deploy the **api**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: apirepo/api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

and the headless service for the **api-deployment**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-headless-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None 
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
```

and that's all. Now you can scale up or down your **web** and **api** deployments based on requests and the service definitions will load-balance those automatically and handle the service discovery.

Comment: what about case when it is not Web and Api, but merely a sidecar container?  And topicstarter don't need autoscaling?  Arghya's answer is exactly on point .

Comment: you are right, and topicstarter could meaning this by saying "pods with multiple containers". my mistake.

Comment: My major takeaway from my scenario is that if you are using more than 1 containers in a pod. The initialDelaySeconds in readinessProbe for every container should be equal to the biggest initialDelaySeconds among all the containers. No point in making the pod running if all the containers are not ready. What do you think?

Comment: may I ask why you need to deploy more than one container in a pod in order to understand the situation?

Comment: Yeah, that is a bad thing, kind of anti-pattern. Some old legacy services, they are getting migrated slowly but for the time being I have to do that.

Comment: then, just use initialDelaySeconds in readinessProbe as you said.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions)

> Ready: the Pod is able to serve requests and should be added to the
> load balancing pools of all matching Services

So if one pod is `ready` then that pods IP will be added to `endpoints` object and service will start sending traffic to that pod. Later if more pods becomes `ready` then those pods IP also get added to `endpoints` object and service will start load balancing traffic between all the pods.

To check pod IPs added to a service you can run `kubectl describe service servicename` and inspect the `Endpoints` section.

To avoid the scenario of traffic being sent to containers in a pod but containers are not yet ready to accept traffic you can use [container probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)

When all the containers inside a pod is ready then only service's `Endpoints` is populated with Pod IP and traffic starts flowing.

Comment: Thanks, Arghya. In container C2, I have added readinessProbe already. In the readinessProbe, the initialDelaySeconds is 25. The port of container C1 is accepting traffic from service. So, should I configure readinessProbe in C1 with initialDelaySeconds of 30? This way, both the containers will get ready at t2. So, when my pod gets running, both the containers will be ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you pay a glimpse to below mentioned snippet, from a deployment.yaml file -

```
spec:
  replicas: 4
    strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
        rollingUpdate:
          maxUnavailable: 25%
```

It shows that for a canary deployment, the 25% criteria shows that, if you have set 4 dedicated replicas in deployment.yaml then whenever 75% of those have been successfully rolled out then allow traffic to be served by that service.

So basically you are having 3/4 replicas alive and you can serve traffic. This is purely configurable.

Answer (score -1):

If the port inside container is not up, then probably no traffic will be forwarded. However, you can take a tcpdump inside the pod and follow the syn and reset flag to provide that

Comment: Thanks, Tutai. the port of container C1 is configured to accept connections from the service. The container C1 gets ready within 1 second. C1 is dependent on C2 to serve a request. But C2 takes time to start. So you mean, if C1 is ready the service will forward requests to the pod? That means for almost 30 seconds, the requests will fail?